# Spring Boot 2 integrate Brave MySQL-Integration into Zipkin

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing

I am trying to integrate the Brave MySql Instrumentation into my Spring Boot 2.x service to automatically let its interceptor enrich my traces with spans concerning MySql-Queries.

The current Gradle-Dependencies are the following

```
compile 'io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:2.4.5'
compile('io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-okhttp3:2.3.1')
compile('io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-mysql:4.14.3')
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:2.0.0.M5')
```

I already configured Sleuth successfully to send traces concerning HTTP-Request to my Zipkin-Server and now I wanted to add some spans for each MySql-Query the service does.

The TracingConfiguration it this:

```
@Configuration
public class TracingConfiguration {
    /** Configuration for how to send spans to Zipkin */
    @Bean
    Sender sender() {
        return OkHttpSender.create("https://myzipkinserver.com/api/v2/spans");
    }

    /** Configuration for how to buffer spans into messages for Zipkin */
    @Bean AsyncReporter<Span> spanReporter() {
        return AsyncReporter.create(sender());
    }

    @Bean Tracing tracing(Reporter<Span> spanListener) {
      return Tracing.newBuilder()
              .spanReporter(spanReporter())
              .build();
  }
}
```

The Query-Interceptor works properly, but my problem now is that the spans are not added to the existing trace but each are added to a new one.

I guess its because of the creation of a new sender/reporter in the configuration, but I have not been able to reuse the existing one created by the Spring Boot Autoconfiguration.
That would moreover remove the necessity to redundantly define the Zipkin-Url (because it is already defined for Zipkin in my application.yml).

I already tried autowiring the Zipkin-Reporter to my Bean, but all I got is a `SpanReporter` - but the Brave-Tracer-Builder requries a `Reporter<Span>`

Do you have any advice for me how to properly wire things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use latest snapshots. Sleuth in latest snapshots uses brave internally so integration will be extremely simple.

Comment: You mean the latest snapshot of org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth? As far as I read it from the history, Brave-Integration was merged in M6 which was not yet released.

Comment: There is no m6 yet so you need to use snapshots

Comment: I now switched to org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:1.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Can you give me a short hint how to integrate Brave MySql-Instrumentation?

Comment: Maybe i wasn't too precise. Please use latest 2.0.0. Snapshots

Comment: Switched to org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT - which does not really make a difference. I am still trying to integrate io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-mysql:4.14.3 but I'm not  able to get it up and running.

Comment: Have you appended proper entries to the URL? https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/instrumentation/mysql/src/main/java/brave/mysql/TracingStatementInterceptor.java#L18

Comment: Yes, I did. I now have the behaviour that each span created by the interceptor is sent to zipkin in an individual trace and not appended to the existing one.

Comment: Ok, I don't think this is a proper place for this conversation.  Please read the documentation, ask questions on Brave's Gitter. Your question here was about how to integrate Brave's mysql to Sleuth and I've answered your question. Could you please mark it as answered?